# App crash when deleting element in Core Data Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm building a SwiftUI app that use Core Data to save the data. I have created a button to delete the element in Core Data. It worked and I didn't modified it, but now the app crashes when I try to delete the element.

```
struct HabitView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var habit: FetchedResults<Habit>.Element
    var body: some View {
        /*
        Rest of the view
        */

        Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            withAnimation {
                DataManager().deleteHabit(habit: habit, context: managedObjectContext)
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function that delete the element in Core Data :

```
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "HabitModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to load the data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    
        context = container.viewContext
    }

    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data saved")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving the data")
        }
    }

    /*
    Other functions
    */

    func deleteHabit(habit: Habit, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        for task in habit.tasksArray {
            context.delete(task)
        }
        
        context.delete(habit)
    
        save(context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing when the app crashes?

Comment: use "@StateObject" attribute to a property declaration and providing an initial value that conforms to the ObservableObject protocol: "@StateObject" var dataManager = DataManager() 
SwiftUI creates a new instance of the object only once for each instance of the structure that declares the object
Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            withAnimation {
                dataManager.deleteHabit(habit: habit, context: managedObjectContext)
                dismiss()
            }
        }

Comment: You are recreating the container every time you call `DataManager()` but without an error it is impossible to tell

Comment: When I run the app and then I try to delete an element, a window is showed to say that the app quit unexpectedly

Comment: If you run it from Xcode you should see the error printed in the console (cmd+shift+c to show the console if it isn't visible)

Comment: @AdR I tried to use StateObject and the code that you have suggested, but I still have the same problem. I don't find any error in the console. I find it strange because my code used to work and I didn't change it but it doesn't work now.

Comment: Try to execute database access in main queue : if not, it could lead to UI code accessing data during database updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you call DataManager().deleteHabit, while the constructor of DataManager has an asynchronous operation to set up the persistent store, coredata wont be able to execute your delete request yet because the store is not fully set up.

You need to move the loadPersistentStores to some other part of the code, before UI generation and execute it only once.